# Python Adding Unique Class Objects to a List

Tags: python, class, loops

I'm having problems when adding objects to a list. When I append objects to the end of a list and then try to loop through the it, every spot on the list just gives me back the most recently added object.

The script compares info from different projects in Excel spreadsheets. I'm using Python for Windows and the win32com.client to access the speadsheets I'm interested in. I read about a few others on Stack Overflow having problems adding unique objects to a list, but I'm pretty sure I don't have the same mistakes that they did (initializing a list in a loop, not providing input attributes when creating a class object).

I can comment out the object creation in the loop and simply add numbers to the list and am able to print out all three unique values, but as soon as I put the object creation call back in, things go wrong. The code below just prints three of the most recently added project. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
class Project:
    """
    Creates an instance for each project
    in the spreadsheet
    """

    def __init__(self, bldg, zone, p_num, p_name, p_mgr,
                 const_mgr, ehs_lias, ehs_const, status,
                 p_type, start, finish):
        self.bldg = bldg
        self.zone = zone
        self.p_num = p_num
        self.p_name = p_name
        self.p_mgr = p_mgr
        self.const_mgr = const_mgr
        self.ehs_lias = ehs_lias
        self.ehs_const = ehs_const
        self.status = status
        self.p_type = p_type
        self.start = start
        self.finish = finish

    def quickPrint(self):
            """ prints quick glance projects details """
            if p_name is None:
                pass
            else:
                print 'Building ' + str(bldg.Value)
                print str(p_name.Value)
                print str(p_type.Value) + " -- " + str(p_mgr.Value)
                print str(start.Value) + " - " + str(finish.Value)


projects = []
for i in range(25, 28):
    bldg = excel.Cells(i,1)
    zone = excel.Cells(i,2)
    p_num = excel.Cells(i,3)
    p_name = excel.Cells(i,4)
    p_mgr = excel.Cells(i,5)
    const_mgr = excel.Cells(i,6)
    ehs_lias = excel.Cells(i,7)
    ehs_const = excel.Cells(i,8)
    status = excel.Cells(i,9)
    p_type = excel.Cells(i,10)
    start = excel.Cells(i,11)
    finish = excel.Cells(i,12)
    projects.append(Project(bldg, zone, p_num, p_name, p_mgr,
                        const_mgr, ehs_lias, ehs_const,
                        status, p_type, start, finish))
projects[0].quickPrint()
projects[1].quickPrint()
projects[2].quickPrint()
```

Comment: What is `quickPrint`?

Comment: A function within the Project class to just print project start/end date and name. I left it out above because it seemed to be working, just printing out a lot of the same thing!

Comment: Well, that's my point: how do you know the problem is not in the printing, rather than the object creation?

Comment: Shouldn't you be pulling the _value_ out of the excel cells? (I say without being certain about the excel library you are using)

Comment: EDIT: I added the quickPrint function for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have defined `quickPrint` incorrectly. As far as it is concerned, `p_name`, `p_type`, `p_mgr`, etc. are not defined, so it looks further up the scope resolution tree, or whatever it's called, and then eventually finds them - where you last defined them in the for loop, which is why it gives you the last value.

Because you have used the same variable names in your loop, you are hiding this issue, and making it more confusing.

```
def quickPrint(self):
        """ prints quick glance projects details """
        if self.p_name is None:
            pass
        else:
            print 'Building ' + str(self.bldg.Value)
            print str(self.p_name.Value)
            print str(self.p_type.Value) + " -- " + str(self.p_mgr.Value)
            print str(self.start.Value) + " - " + str(self.finish.Value)
```

example:

```
class Project(object):
  def __init__(self, argument):
    self.argument = argument

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(argument)

projects = []  
for i in range(10):
  argument = i
  projects.append(Project(argument))

print projects
```

this outputs `[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`

changing the `__repr__(self):` definition to have `self.argument` fixes it.

Comment: It doesn't look like he/she is adding references to the same object. Are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: @khelwood - You're right. I've updated it to be what i believe to be the problem.

Comment: I used your second suggestion and get an error while printing. I can look up individual objects and their attributes by calling them individually, so they are at least properly being inserted into the list. 

Now it looks like @DanielRoseman was right, the problem is in my quickPrint() function.

Thanks Will!